Connection Manager SSIS for SQL Server
I am trying to connect in a localhost database (SQL Server database) using SSIS. To do this I created an OLE DB Connection manager but I obtain the following errors:


For me is more correct the second one, but it says that the server does not exists, but I do have a localhost connection.
Can you help me on this, please?
I tried to connect using OLE DB and Native OLE DB for SQL Server Connection Managers

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

If you are getting a permission error, have you checked the SQL Server logs?

Sorry for the images, but I checked alreaady the logs, nothing of important

Can you show exactly the ssms login screen that "works" according to you
